# Правильно ли всё со знаками препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Помимо этого, в любой сфере деятельности отношение к критике как к потенциально полезным советам, а не как к личным нападкам считается положительной чертой.

Answer (score 1):

После *а не как к личным нападкам* нужна запятая (закрывающая оборот).

Answer (score 1):

Знаки поставлены верно, но предожение сложно для прочтения и восприятия.

Возможное редактирование:

*Помимо этого, в любой сфере деятельности такое отношение к критике — **как к потенциально полезным советам, а не как к личным нападкам** — считается положительной чертой.*